# Error starting Forem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forem

I'm using Rails 3.2.11/Ruby 1.9.2

I installed Forem as per the Github instructions.

On install, it crashed at the 'Creating default forum and topic', first error line being:

```
../gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing': undefined method `forem_moderate_posts?' for #<User:0x007f80d5bf5ba0> (NoMethodError)
```

I continued anyway...

I pasted in the line for routes (there actually isnt any documentation on how to actually use Forem - only on how to install it!)

```
mount Forem::Engine, :at => '/members/community'
```

When I browse to

```
http://localhost:3000/members/community/forums
```

I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Forem::ForumsController#show

Couldn't find Forem::Forum with id=forums

Googling brings up 1 related article, relating to Rails 4 and suggests adding lines to eg

```
app/models/forem/category.rb
```

However, my app doesnt have a models/forem folder - don't know if thats because installation crashed or what.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Update - I'd been having a nokogiri build warning for a while, so I sorted that & re-installed Forem. It now ran to the end with a success note, but the same error still persists

Comment: Update 2 - set the default route back to '/' and the errors changed to path-related errors on my layout file. Put main_app in front of the layout paths and finally got a page. This looks too much like hard work...